# BES 5.0 and pushing ringer profiles

Tags: blackberry, bes

I've been doing a bit of investigation and I can't seem to figure out if I can push a new ringer profile to my Blackberry users.  I have about 45 users connected to BES 5.0.  Specifically, I'm trying to create an Extra Loud profile for everyone to use.  (Trust me, it's probably easier for me to spend 10 hours figuring this out rather than try and teach them how to create a new profile)

Anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible.

Comment: Righto.  I think if I want to do something like that, I need to create an application and push it.